# Popover for items within an accordion (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 and I'm trying to create a popover for some items within an accordion. I’m able to create a popover but it does not get displayed at the correct position?
How can I display the popover next to the hovered item?

My code is here: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/GuGYSTExtR)

```
 $('#tst1').popover({
        trigger: 'hover',
        title: 'my title',
        animation: true,
        content: '<p>Some text</p>',
        html: true,
        placement: 'bottom'
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with accordion. The elements that you apply popover `a.machineStateLink` do not have dimentions. Just make them inline-blocks or something.

```
.machineStateLink{
   display:inline-block;
}
```